# Probability density functions C

Tags: probability-distributions

Please excuse my use of images [image]

> The answer to this is that no the first function cannot be a pdf, but the second one can with a restriction. All explanations I try to look just confuse me further.

[image]

> Why for the first function since we have negative values it cannot be a pdf, but for the second one we are allowed to put a restriction? I calculated the $C$ for both functions; for the first one I got a negative $C$ and for the second one I got a positive $C$, does this have anything to do with the decision?
>
> Also an explanation of what $f(5/2)<0$ means and why we are using it for the second function would be appreciated

Comment: Both functions cannot be a density. Basically if there is any sign change within the support it cannot be a density.

Comment: @KarnWatcharasupat Both my professor and the solution I posted say that we can.

Comment: You are reading the solution incorrectly. The final sentence, albeit confusing and misleading, is **not** saying that the second function can be a density. What it is *trying* to say is this: if $f(x)$ has exactly two roots, one at $x=0$ and another greater than $\frac{5}{2}$, then the function $$g(x)=\begin{cases}Cf(x) & x\in(0,\frac{5}{2})\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ *can* be a density, by choosing $C$ appropriately. For in that case, $f$ does not change sign on the interval $(0,\frac{5}{2})$. But the two functions you're given, $f(x)=2x-x^3$ and $f(x)=2x-x^2$, don't have this property.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Is there a corresponding $g(x)$ for the first function as well?

Comment: What? I used different notation from your solution; I called $g(x)$ what your solution calls $f(x)$. But what you call it is immaterial. Just read carefully what I said.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Yes I understand, I'm asking if we can construct a $g(x)$ that could be a density for the first function in my question. In the solution it says simply no for the first function, but for the second function we are able to construct the $g(x)$ that you wrote. If not, what is the reason for that?

Comment: The whole point is that if $f(x)$ is continuous and *has no roots* between $0$ and $\frac{5}{2}$, then $f(x)$ can't change sign on that interval, so  $$g(x)=\begin{cases}Cf(x) & x\in(0,\frac{5}{2})\\0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ *can* be a density. I don't know why the final sentence was tacked on after the second example (perhaps it was meant to be the moral of *both* examples); it applies just as well to the first example, yes.

Comment: @symplectomorphic If it applies just as well to the first example, then why did two independent sources say no for the first function, but gave the restriction for the second?

Comment: Your sources are stupid and poorly written, that's why. Moreover, it's not a "restriction" for the second function. It's a *conclusion* or *generalization* based on the two exercises in total. The point is a general one. It has nothing to do with the second example alone. I've said that many times now.

Comment: I got it now, I misread my professor. He implied your solution in a way that made it seem that he was saying no for the first, yes for the second. However, the solution included in my question didn't help me understand this